# Xcode Saving UIDatepicker to be displayed in a label

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

The following code is to show my UIDatepicker:

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
    NSString *title = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" : @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" ;
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", title, NSLocalizedString(@"Please Select A Date", @"")]
                                  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"I've Made My Choice", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
}
```

It all works properly, but what I'd like to do is to display the users choice into a label which I have named " label1 ". Can anyone help? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is the updated code:

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
NSString *title = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ? @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" : @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" ;
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", title, NSLocalizedString(@"Please Select A Date", @"")]
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"I've Made My Choice", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
[datePicker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(updateLabel:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

}

```
- (void)updateLabel:(id)sender {
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
[df release];


/* the following allows you to choose the date components
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

 int hour   =    [[calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit    fromDate:[datePicker date]] hour];
 int minute =    [[calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit  fromDate:[datePicker date]] minute];

 int year   =    [[calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit    fromDate:[datePicker date]] year];
 int month  =    [[calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit   fromDate:[datePicker date]] month];
 int day    =    [[calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit     fromDate:[datePicker date]] day];
 */
```

}
 That's for the .m , my .xib has the 'label' tied properly too :) just getting a (null) value whenever I choose my date :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label1;
@end
```

### .m

```
@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize label1;
/*
     All of your code goes here
 */
@end
```

### Interface Builder

[image]

---

Also add the following to your `showActionSheet:`

```
[datePicker addTarget:self
               action:@selector(updateLabel:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

**This should update your label from `datePicker`:**

```
-(void)updateLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
    [df release];


    /* the following allows you to choose the date components
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    int hour   =    [[calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit    fromDate:[datePicker date]] hour];
    int minute =    [[calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit  fromDate:[datePicker date]] minute];

    int year   =    [[calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit    fromDate:[datePicker date]] year];
    int month  =    [[calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit   fromDate:[datePicker date]] month];
    int day    =    [[calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit     fromDate:[datePicker date]] day];
      */
}
```

Comment: When I go to add that in, I get "datePicker" undeclared, however when I update my .h file to have an NSString *datePicker; , I get " request for member 'date' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: Oh, yea, sorry, define datePicker in your header, using @property, then in your .m, use @synthesize. Then in your "showActionSheet, remove the "UIDatePicker *".

Comment: Yes, if you use an XIB, then you need to use @property and IBOutlet in your header / @synthesize in .m and connect everything in Interface Builder.

Comment: When I go to connect the datePicker to the label, it won't connect. It acts like the label isn't on the interface, even with a @property and IBOutlet in the header and with @synthesize in the .m .  In my .h:  IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
 IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
 both with the appropriate @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker; and @synthesized them both in the .m

Comment: datePicker is the UIDatePicker, so naturally it wont connect to your UILabel. You connect label1 to your Label in IB, then connect datePicker to the UIDatePicker in IB

Comment: the label1 won't connect to Label at all in IB, I don't have a specific UIDatePicker for the interface, it's all in code (that I know of so far, I never "dragged" anything from the library to the screen

Comment: Okay, so if you create your datePicker in code, then theres no need to hook it up in IB, @property & @synthesize are important though.

Comment: Something isn't right then because the label doesn't become updated upon selection of date.

Comment: here's what the end of the action sheet looks like ...       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"I've Made My Choice", nil];
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
 UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
 [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
 
 [datePicker addTarget:self
       action:@selector(updateLabel:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 
}

Comment: Did you connect the label in Interface Builder?

Comment: It won't, when I go to connect anything to the label, nothing will happen. it acts like the label isn't even there but it is.

Comment: I've edited my answer with more code and a screenshot. Beyond this, you can hire me to write your app for you ;-)

Comment: NOW I'm getting some activity on the Label updating :) but whenever I choose something it just says (null) :( I put my updated code above. You've been a HUGE HELP! Thx !

Comment: I gave props :) but unfortunately I've messed with this code for literally hours and all I've gotten still was a (null) displayed. Thank you though for getting me this far!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here I shows that `UIDatePicker` in `UITableview` cell.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   
    // Make a new view, or do what you want here    
    UIDatePicker *pv = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,185,0,0)];    
    [self.view addSubview:pv];    
    return NO;    
}
```

If you are using `UITableView`, then use following in order to show `UIDatePicker` instead of keyboard.

```
if (0 == indexPath.row) {
    cell.rightTextField.placeholder = @”Date”;
    cell.rightTextField.text = [coAccident strDateTime];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 185, 0)];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDateInLabel :) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
cell.rightTextField.inputView = datePicker;
} 

- (IBAction)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker * datePicker = (UIDatePicker*)sender;
    CAccidentVO* coAccident = [m_arrVehicles objectAtIndex:1];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;   
    [coAccident setStrDateTime:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]]];  
    [df release];  
    [m_tvVehicleDetails reloadData];
}
```