# How to show selected date on button using datepicker?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5.1

when i click on my button am able to show date picker sucessfully.But when i am selecting date from the date picker  I am unble to show the selected date on `UIbutton`. plz help me

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)btnDateClicked:(id)sender
{ 
UIActionSheet *actionSheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet1 setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);


UIDatePicker *pView=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

pView.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate; 

NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

// NSDate *date=[df dateFromString:self.hController.fromDateTime];

// [pView setDate:date animated:YES];

self.datePicker=pView;

[actionSheet1 addSubview:self.datePicker];

[pView release];

UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];

closeButton.momentary = YES; 

closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);

closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[actionSheet1 addSubview:closeButton];

[closeButton release];

[actionSheet1 showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

[actionSheet1 setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

self.actionSheet=actionSheet1;

[actionSheet1 release];
}
///////////////////////////////////
- (void)dismissActionSheet1:(id)sender
{
[self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];   

//NSString *str=[df stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]; 

//self.hController.selectDate=str;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate` methods for this.Create an array of your dates Which you are showing in the pickerView and use the following method.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{

[ closeButton setTitle:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@",[datesArray objectAtIndex:row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: I want to show the calender in datepicker not an array of dates

Comment: Here is an exact link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841205/xcode-saving-uidatepicker-to-be-displayed-in-a-label enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Add some label as subview to the button on whose click event pickerview is shown.on selecting date from date picker update the label text to the selected date

Answer (score 0):

Use this to update title on button

```
[ closeButton setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do connection of button using IBOutlet and and then in following method set the text of button using

```
  - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
     {
        [ closeButton setTitle:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@",[datesArray objectAtIndex:row]]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     }
```

And you are done :)