# How to show selected UIDatePicker date as UIButton text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uibutton

I'm having `UIImage` with arrow mark,on that I had place custom button.
When i clicked this button I want to Show te date picker.
After selecting the date from date-picker,I need to show selected date as button text.
I'm using the button by XIB.

Comment: Go through this [Datepicker and Button][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177261/how-to-show-selected-date-on-button-using-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code ,

```
[self.DatePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(SetDatePickerTime:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    -(void)SetDatePickerTime:(id)sender
    {
       NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyy"];

        NSString *title = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.DatePicker.date];
        NSLog(@"%@",[outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.DatePicker.date]);

       [yourButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this from the method you dismiss the datePicker

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self.datePicker date]];

[self.dateButton setTitle:dateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```